# Entity Framework WHERE OR Query Using IQueryable In A Loop

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am building up a medium-sized query using Entity Framework Core, and in one section of my code, I am looping through a list of objects.

In this list, if a specific criterion is met, I want to create a WHERE query (Which is fine and working). However, this loop creates a WHERE AND query once the IQueryable is iterated. I want this loop to create a WHERE OR? Is this possible?

Example of the loop with where query (queryable = IQueryable). So in this loop, I am trying to achieve many WHERE OR's instead of WHERE AND's. Hope that makes sense.

```
foreach (var rfs in newsItemQuery.MyData.Where(x => x.Selected))
{
    if (rfs.IncludeNegative == false && rfs.IncludeNeutral == false)
    {
        queryable = queryable.Where(x => x.Id == rfs.Id && x.IsNegative == false && x.IsNeutral == false);
    }
    else if (rfs.IncludeNegative == false && rfs.IncludeNeutral)
    {
        queryable = queryable.Where(x => x.Id == rfs.Id && x.IsNegative == false);
    }
    else if (rfs.IncludeNegative && rfs.IncludeNeutral == false)
    {
        queryable = queryable.Where(x => x.Id == rfs.Id && x.IsNeutral == false);
    }
    else
    {
        queryable = queryable.Where(x => x.Id == rfs.Id);   
    }
}
```

Comment: Use [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) from  [LINQKi](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit). If you don't want dependency, just extract it's code into your project.

Comment: Thanks. I had already found it and implemented it. Great package :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have done this by making use of the fantastic Nuget package LinqKit

https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit

This allows you to use the predicate builder, which has an .Or option

```
IQueryable<Product> SearchProducts (params string[] keywords)
{
  var predicate = PredicateBuilder.New<Product>();

  foreach (string keyword in keywords)
  {
    string temp = keyword;
    predicate = predicate.Or (p => p.Description.Contains (temp));
  }
  return dataContext.Products.Where (predicate);
}
```